# Buying stamps in Barcelona Sants station

Tags: trains, mail, barcelona

Earlier today, I bought some postcards in Barcelona, from a gift shop at a museum which didn't sell stamps. I then retired to a nearby cafe for a coffee, and wrote the postcards. After that, I hopped on the metro to Barcelona Sants station, and utterly failed to find anywhere to sell me any stamps for them, and I couldn't even find a postbox...

For me this in now moot, as my TGV has whisked me across the border, and consequently these postcards will have to have French stamps instead. However, for next time, I'm left with the question - is it possible in Barcelona Sants station to buy stamps then post letters? Or failing that, how nearby would one have to venture to do so?

Answer (score 5):

The most ubiquitous kind of place that sells stamps in Spain is tobacconists (*[estancos](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estanco)*): in addition to selling cigarettes, most of them sell other regulated products such as stamps. Look for a sign that says “tabacos” (they often sell stamps even if there is no visible indication on the outside).

The [map of Barcelona Sants](http://www.adif.es/en_US//infraestructuras/planos/estaciones/plano_71801.pdf) (linked from the [ADIF station information page]([Station information](http://www.adif.es/en_US/infraestructuras/estaciones/71801/informacion_000097.shtml)) lists a tobacconist (48 *Articulos de fumador*) on the street level on Plaça Països Catalans (in front of the station).

[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/search/estanco/@41.3800996,2.1434671,16z/data=!4m5!2m4!3m3!1sestanco!2sBarcelona-Sants,+Spain!3s0x12a49880d2e88101:0x5991aa84fd5ac015) doesn't know about this shop, but it also doesn't know one near Plaça Espanya which I know for a fact exists, and I would be extremely surprised if a major station lacked a tobacconist.

There is probably a [yellow post box](http://suitelife.com/2012/02/14/barcelona-post-office-correos-how-it-works-and-how-to-use-it/) in the station as well. The tobacconist or the tourist information center should know.

Comment: Note in Barcelona the sign will be "Tabacs", in Catalan. And Google maps shows it if you search the area for that word. There is a postbox just outside the station on the corner where that station map shows the Lavazza cafe ( number 1).